# BI Publisher Ring Chart Thickness

Tags: oracle, charts, bi-publisher

I am relatively new to BI Publisher and I have to date only worked with line and bar charts.

I am working on a report that uses Ring Charts, and the default thickness of the chart is too much. I want it to look like a hoola hoop and not a doughnut, as below. But I dont know what node to change in the XML, can someone advise?

**Chart Currently looks like this:**

[image: Current Output]

**I would like it to look like this:**

[image: Desired Output]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Chart Code**

```
<Graph seriesEffect="SE_NONE" graphType="RING">
   <LegendArea visible="false" />
   <SeriesItems>
      <Series id="0" color="#447A27" />
      <Series id="1" color="#96b27f" />
      <Series id="2" color="#c4c5c7" />
      <Series id="3" color="#EA4848" />
      <Series id="4" color="#C41C24" />
   </SeriesItems>
   <SliceLabel visible="false">
      <ViewFormat decimalDigit="0" decimalDigitUsed="true" />
   </SliceLabel>
   <LocalGridData colCount="1" rowCount="{count(.//DATASET[condition='Test'])}">
      <RowLabels>
         <xsl:for-each select=".//DATASET[condition='Test']" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <Label>
                <xsl:value-of select="QUALITY_LEVEL" />
            </Label>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </RowLabels>
      <DataValues>
         <xsl:for-each select=".//DATASET[condition='Test']" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <RowData>
                <Cell>
                   <xsl:value-of select="COUNT" />
                </Cell>
            </RowData>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </DataValues>
   </LocalGridData>
   <RingTotalLabel>
      <GraphFont size="50" fontColor="#c4c5c7" />
   </RingTotalLabel>
</Graph>
```